# Rx-Java replace Observable in case of error

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I have 2 URLs to fetch the data, for example: `\location_1\{userid}` and `\location_2\{userid}`. for the first i get the list of the users and then need to fetch user details by above requests. the issue is that i need to call the `\location_1\{userid}` and in case there is an error(exception) fetch the data from `\location_2\{userid}`. is it possible to make it with single rx-chain? i've tried `try/catch` as described [here](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/12/08/error-handling-in-rxjava/) but looks catch newer calls, only `onErrorResumeNext` calls.

```
Observable<List<TestModel2>> observable = apiTest
     .performTest()
     .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
     .flatMap(testModel -> {

        try
        {
            return apiTest.performTest2(testModel.userId);

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            return apiTest.performTest3(testModel.userId);
        }

      }).doOnNext(testModel2 -> {Log.d("TestItemData", "doOnNext --- " + testModel2.title);})
            .onErrorResumeNext(throwable ->{
                            Log.d("TestItemData", "onErrorResumeNext -------- ");
                            return Observable.empty();
                         })
            .toList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `onErrorResumeNext` (as you already did a bit later in the flow):

```
Observable<List<TestModel2>> observable = apiTest
.performTest()
.flatMapIterable(items -> items)
.flatMap(testModel -> 
    apiTest.performTest2(testModel.userId)
    .onErrorResumeNext(e -> apiTest.performTest3(testModel.userId)); // <----------------
)
.doOnNext(testModel2 -> {
    Log.d("TestItemData", "doOnNext --- " + testModel2.title);
})
.onErrorResumeNext(throwable ->{
    Log.d("TestItemData", "onErrorResumeNext -------- ");
    return Observable.empty();
})
.toList()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```